# How to convert a sketch to 3 dimensions in FreeCAD?

Tags: cad

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Basic_Part_Design_Tutorial) but I'm getting stuck on the "Now in the Combo View..." section.

I've created my 2d sketch, and it then tells me to click on the "Pad a selected sketch" toolbar button. I do that, select "Two dimensions" for Type, enter 26.5 mm for both lengths, click OK...and then nothing happens. I can click the view buttons to change perspectives in 3d, but I can't edit the object in 3d or spin the view using the cursor. It appears to still be constrained by the original YZ plane.

It tells me to select the "Rectangle" tool, but this isn't an option, unless I doubleclick on the sketch inside the new Pad object, but even then, the sketch only allows me to draw a rectangle on the YZ plane, not the new XZ plane that should have been created.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the view where I'm stuck:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the image I reckon you have done the "pad" of the sketch and then re-entered into editing the same sketch.

To get to grips with what you have done/where you are: Click `/Model\`  just above <kbd>Close</kbd> and you should see a the text "Pad".
Click on "Pad" and press the space bar and your sketch will show up WITHOUT the part you created with it.

Now, to get further you need to switch back to the `/Tasks\` tab and click close.

A FreeCAD Sketch is just two dimensions, so for addition of ONE feature at a time. 
How: optionally select a surface to attach the sketch to, then create the sketch, close it and you will have the option to either "Pad" (add 3D-object outline attached to the surface) or create a sketch-defined hole in the previously selected surface.
And "optionally" above means that you can start a new 3D object by simply creating sketch from scratch.

For least amount of trouble; keep sketches as simple as possible. As there are very advanced features it is easy to get carried away. Advanced features are just that; "advanced" - you need to get to know them to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 0):

What happened, as the first response also says, is you re-entered the same sketch. Double clicking on the pad will do that.

What you want to do is use the touchpad view controls, as this will allow you to use Shift+Left Mouse Button to rotate, and Shift to move. Then, rotate the pad to the face you want, and SINGLE click on it. Then click 'new sketch.' This will automatically start drawing a new object onto the face you have selected.

The tutorial is kinda vague about this, and is more geared to someone with existing CAD knowledge, rather than a pure beginner.